# Best way to model one to many relationship in OOP

Tags: oop, object, model, one-to-many

I'm working in a project which involves a one to many relation in the database.
A simple example of this would be a teacher that teaches many courses but a course can be taught by just one teacher.
My question is what would be the best way to model this?

The first object is Teacher:

```
class Teacher{
    public int id;
    public String name;
    public String lastName;
    ...
}
```

The thing is how would the course class look like?
Option 1:

```
class Course{
    public int idCourse;
    public String courseDescription;
    **public int teacherId;**
    ...
}
```

Option 2:

```
class Course{
    public int idCourse;
    public String courseDescription;
    **public Teacher teacher;**
    ...
}
```

Comment: This is a bit opinion based. But if you are modeling this strictly like a database, that would be Option 1 since in a relational database you'd reference objects (records) by their primary key. The disadvantage is that if you have a course and want to find the teacher, you have to look up the teacher object given the id, whereas in Option 2, you have the teacher object already (or at least a reference to it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Option 2 (having a reference to the teacher object) seems to be more functional from an OOP perspective.

In a usual flow, you would create a course object like :

```
Teacher t = new Teacher('first_name', 'last_name');
Course c = new Course('Math course');
c.setTeacher(t);
```

Your option 1 highlights what the relational database schema behind this might look like. Here's a good read on that :
https://www.lifewire.com/one-to-many-relationships-1019756#:~:text=A%20teacher%20can%20teach%20multiple,one%20teacher%20to%20multiple%20courses.

Once the code above is committed, it could fire two insert queries underlying to add the new teacher in teachers table and add the new course (along with the teacher ID), in the course table.